# Fields initialized with MockitoAnnotations.openMocks() @beforeClass are null in other tests of the same class

Tags: java, mockito, java-17

Fields initialized with MockitoAnnotations.openMocks() @beforeClass are null in other tests of the same class.

```
public class AitGetMyDetailsTest extends BaseMocks {

@InjectMocks
private AitGetMyDetails storedProcedure;

@BeforeClass
public void openMocks() throws Exception {
    super.openMocks(); //invokes MockitoAnnotations.openMocks() from extended custom class
    storedProcedure.afterPropertiesSet(); **//till here all the fields of stored procedure object fields are initialized as expected**
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    MyObj mockMyObj = Mockito.mock(MyObj.class);
    storedProcedure.execute(mockMyObj, 67,45); **//ISSUE : storedProcedure object fields are null.**
}
}


public abstract class BaseMocks {

@Mock
protected RowMapper<Object> mockRowMapper;

@Mock
protected Connection mockConnection;

@Mock
protected CallableStatement mockStatement;

@Mock
protected DataSourceProvider dsProvider;

@Mock
public DataSource mockDataSource;

final MockResultSet mockResultSet = new MockResultSet("");

@BeforeClass
protected void openMocks() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(dsProvider.getDatasource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockDataSource);
    Mockito.when(mockDataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
    Mockito.when(mockConnection.prepareCall(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockStatement);
    Mockito.when(mockStatement.getResultSet()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
}

@BeforeMethod
protected void resetMocks() throws SQLException {
    Mockito.reset(mockRowMapper);
    Mockito.when(mockStatement.getMoreResults()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
}
}
```

The same code was working earlier with jdk 1.8 and MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(). Not able to figure out if there is a difference between MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() vs MockitoAnnotations.openMocks()

Comment: What is super.openMocks() calling? Presumably not MockitoAnnotations.openMocks() as MockitoAnnotations is a final class.

Comment: Hi, it calls MockitoAnnotations.openMocks() invocation from another extended class.